# Stop and continue a QThread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

so i'm making a scanning virus app. I have a class called ScanThread that use to find, display and scan files and folders:
ScanThread.h:

```
// scanthread.h
#ifndef SCANTHREAD_H
#define SCANTHREAD_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QWaitCondition>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "stack.h"
#include <windows.h>

class ScanThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    static ScanThread* getInstance();

    ~ScanThread();

    // Add a public function to stop the thread
    void stopThread();

private:
    ScanThread(){};
    static ScanThread *instance;
    void run(void);
    void scanFolder(std::string sFolder);

signals:
    void scanDone(QString data);
    void scanningFile(QString sFile);
    void setTimeScanned(int timeScanned);
    void setFilesTotal(int scannedFiles);
    void setMalwareDetected(int malwareDetected);

private:

    MainWindow *m_mainWindow;
    std::string m_sFolderScan;
    static Stack *m_stack;

public:
    void scan(WCHAR* widepathBuffer);
    bool paused, requested = false;
    typedef BOOL(*ScanFile)(WCHAR* szFile, WCHAR* szMalwarename, int iMalwareBufSize, WCHAR* szEvent, int iEventBufSize);
    HINSTANCE atpLoad = LoadLibrary(TEXT("D:\\SmartIR Agent\\agentwindows\\Debug\\kaveLoader.dll"));
    ScanFile scanProc;
    WIN32_FIND_DATAA FindFileData;
    QString sFolderScan;
    WCHAR malwareName[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    WCHAR eventName[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    WCHAR* widePathBuffer;
    int malwareDetected = 0;
    int timeScanned;
    int scannedFiles = 0;
    double progress;
    WCHAR* convertToWideString(const QString& folder, const std::string& cFileName);
    void setMainWindow(MainWindow *mainW)
    {
        this->m_mainWindow = mainW;
    }
    void setFolderScan(std::string folder)
    {
        this->m_sFolderScan = folder;
    }
};

#endif // SCANTHREAD_H
```

Here's the constructor of the class:
ScanThread.cpp:

```
#include "scanthread.h"
#include <chrono>
#include "stack.h"
ScanThread* ScanThread::instance = nullptr;
Stack* ScanThread::m_stack = new Stack();
ScanThread* ScanThread::getInstance()
{
    if (!instance)
    {
        instance = new ScanThread();
        //m_stack = new Stack();
    }
    return instance;
}



ScanThread::~ScanThread()
{
     delete m_stack;
}

void ScanThread::scanFolder(std::string sFolder)
{

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::string sFolderFind;
    HANDLE  hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;


    char* szPath = new char[MAX_PATH + 1];
    ZeroMemory(szPath, MAX_PATH + 1);
    strcpy_s(szPath, MAX_PATH,sFolder.c_str());

    m_stack->Push(szPath);

    while (!m_stack->isStackEmpty()) {
        szPath = m_stack->Pop();
        sFolderScan = szPath;
        sFolderFind = std::string(szPath) + "\\*.*";
        /*if (sFolderScan.toStdString() == pathSkip)
        {
            delete[] szPath;
            continue;
        }*/
        hFind = FindFirstFileA(sFolderFind.c_str(), &FindFileData);
        if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            delete[] szPath;
            szPath = NULL;
            continue;
        }
        do
        {
            qDebug() << requested;
            if (FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
                std::string sFol = FindFileData.cFileName;
                if (sFol == "." || sFol == "..")
                {
                    continue;
                }
                char* szPath2 = new char[MAX_PATH + 1];
                ZeroMemory(szPath2, MAX_PATH + 1);
                strcpy_s(szPath2, MAX_PATH, QString::fromStdString(sFolderScan.toStdString() + "\\" + FindFileData.cFileName).toStdString().c_str());
                m_stack->Push(szPath2);
                scannedFiles++;
            }
            else
            {
                emit scanningFile(QString::fromStdString(sFolderScan.toStdString() + "\\" + FindFileData.cFileName));
                widePathBuffer = convertToWideString(sFolderScan, FindFileData.cFileName);
                scan(widePathBuffer);
            }
            if (requested == true)
            {
                break;
            }

        }while (FindNextFileA(hFind, &FindFileData));

        FindClose(hFind);
        delete[] szPath;
        szPath = NULL;
    }
    if (!m_stack->isStackEmpty())
        m_stack->FreeStack();
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(end - start);
    timeScanned = duration.count();
    emit setFilesTotal(scannedFiles);
    emit setTimeScanned(timeScanned);
    emit setMalwareDetected(malwareDetected);
}
void ScanThread::run(void)
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(scanDone(QString)), m_mainWindow, SLOT(ScanDone(QString)));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(scanningFile(QString)), m_mainWindow, SLOT(scanningFile(QString)));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(setMalwareDetected(int)), m_mainWindow, SLOT(setMalwareDetected(int)));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(setFilesTotal(int)), m_mainWindow, SLOT(setFilesTotal(int)));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(setTimeScanned(int)),m_mainWindow, SLOT(setTimeScanned(int)));
    scanFolder(m_sFolderScan);
    this->exec();
}
WCHAR* ScanThread::convertToWideString(const QString& folder, const std::string& cFileName)
{
    std::wstring wideFolder = folder.toStdWString();
    std::wstring wideFileName(cFileName.begin(), cFileName.end());
    std::wstring widePath = wideFolder + L"\\" + wideFileName;
    widePathBuffer = new WCHAR[widePath.length() + 1];
    wcscpy(widePathBuffer, widePath.c_str());
    return widePathBuffer;
}
void ScanThread::scan(WCHAR* widePathBuffer)
{
    scanProc = (ScanFile)GetProcAddress(atpLoad, "edrf503_2");
    scanProc(widePathBuffer,malwareName, MAX_PATH, eventName, MAX_PATH);
    if (scanProc(widePathBuffer,malwareName, MAX_PATH, eventName, MAX_PATH) == 1)
    {
        malwareDetected++;
    }
}
```

I have another class called StopScanning. So basically this class pops a window and ask the user if they want to stop the scanning process or not.
StopScanning.h:

```
#ifndef STOPSCANNING_H
#define STOPSCANNING_H

#include <QDialog>
#include "mainwindow.h"

namespace Ui {
class StopScanning;
}

class StopScanning : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow *m;
public:
    explicit StopScanning(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~StopScanning();

public slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

    void on_cancelButton_clicked();

    void on_stopButton_clicked();
signals:
    void setRequestedSignal();
public:
    Ui::StopScanning *ui;
    bool requested;
    void setMainWindow(MainWindow *m )
    {
        this->m = m;
    }
};

#endif // STOPSCANNING_H
```

StopScanning.cpp:

```
#include "stopscanning.h"
#include "ui_stopscanning.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "scan.h"
#include "scanthread.h"
StopScanning::StopScanning(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::StopScanning)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

StopScanning::~StopScanning()
{
    delete ui;
}

void StopScanning::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    close();
}

void StopScanning::on_cancelButton_clicked()
{
    m->cancelStopScan();
    close();
}


void StopScanning::on_stopButton_clicked()
{
    std::string sFolder;
    ScanThread *thread = ScanThread::getInstance();
    thread->requested = true;
    //thread->scannedFiles = 0;
    //thread->timeScanned = 0;
    //thread->malwareDetected = 0;
    //thread->quit();
    m->stopScan();
    Scan::getInstance()->stopScan();
    close();
}
```

Here's the GUI of the main app:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvBBT.png)
Here's the GUI of the StopScanning
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SF8i.png)
So when the Scan button is clicked, the ScanThread will be called and scan the folder or file chosen, the Scan button will change its text to Stop. Now i want it to run like this: when the Scan button is clicked, the ScanThread will run and scan all the files or folders chosen, and change the Scan button to Stop, and when the Stop button is clicked, the StopScanning window will pop. If the user clicked the Stop button, the scanning thread will be stopped, else the thread will continue to run. And if the scanning thread is stopped, if the user doesn't chose another file or folder, when the Scan button is clicked, the scan thread will continue to run at the point where it was stopped earlier.

I've managed to stop the thread by adding a bool variable call requested. If the Stop button in the StopScanning is clicked, it will turn the requested to true and break the while loop in the scanFolder method in ScanThread, but when i clicked the Scan button in the main GUI app the thread starts from the beginning, how can i implement the continuing running process of the thread. I know my post is quite long and quite annoying but I would be pleased to receive some help. Thanh you!

Comment: I think it would help to read about condition variables.

Comment: Unrelated: You could _vastly_ simplify your code if you use the Qt objects and data structures like QDir and QStack.

Comment: Also consider using `QString` rather than manually allocating/managing memory for `char* szPath` etc.

Comment: What is your rational for using Qt instead of standard C++? I would write most of the code as a static library using standard C++ as much as possible and write unit tests for that and reserve the use of Qt for a seperate UI application. (In the end you probably need to be able to run the scanner without UI anyway)

Answer (score 3):

If you separate the scanning object from the thread it is running on you can simply use cross-thread Qt signals and slots to stop and restart the scanning loop.
Concretely:

```
class ScanObject {
...
public:
  ScanObject(std::string root) : requested(true) {
    /* Populate the stack with root */
  }
public slots:
  void stopScanning() { requested = false; }
  void continueScanning() { if (requested) { requested = false; scan(); } }

private:
  void scan() {
    while (!requested && !stack.empty()) {
      // Take an item from the stack and process it
      // if the item is a directory, push all directory items to the stack
      // if the item is a file, scan it.
      QEventloop::processEvents(); // allow processing signals
  }
}
```

and to set it up:

```
QThread *scanningThread = new QThread;
ScanObject *scanObject = new ScanObject;
scanObject->moveToThread(scanningThread);
QObject::connect(scanningThread, &QThread::started, scanObject, &ScanObject::continueScanning);
scanningThread->start();
```